# Capturing UITextView data in an NSString

Tags: iphone

[image]
Hey all,

I am trying to accomplish something very simple yet getting an error and it's driving me nuts.

here is what I am doing:

Function 1:

```
-(id)initWithText:(NSString *)text1 :(NSString *)text2 :(NSString *)text3 :(NSString *)text4 :(NSString *)text5

{
```

here I do the assignment. I have not initialized the NSString date, projectName, task, duration and comment, but I don't see that causing any trouble.

```
 date=text1;
 projectName=text2;
 task=text3;
 duration=text4;

 if ([text5 isEqualToString:@"Add Comment"]==TRUE || [text5 isEqualToString:@""]==TRUE) 
 {
  comment=@"No Comment";
 }    

 else {
  comment=text5;
 }
```

date, duration, task ,projectname, comment are all NSString type.

This function gets called in a different viewController using the statement:

Function1 Call:

```
[self.summaryViewController initWithText:self.dateDisplay.text :self.projectNameDisplay.text:self.taskDisplay.text:self.durationDisplay.text:commentText.text];
```

where dateDisplay, projectNameDisplay, taskDisplay, durationDisplay are all UILabels and commentText is a UITextView

---

now I try to save the values captured through the function into a database using another function.

Function2:

```
-(void) insertValues:(NSString *)text1 :(NSString *)text2 :(NSString *)text3 :(NSString *)text4 :(NSString *)text5
{

 if([self openDB]==TRUE)

   {
    NSString *sql  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO mastertable(_date,_projectName,_task,_duration,_comment,_status) VALUES ('%@','%@','%@','%@','%@','Pending');",text1, text2, text3, text4, text5];

    char *err;

    NSLog(sql);

  if(sqlite3_exec(database,[sql UTF8String], NULL, NULL, &err) !=SQLITE_OK)
   {

    NSAssert(0, @"error inserting values into table");
    sqlite3_close(database);
   }

   else
   {
    NSLog(@"Entry Made");

                sqlite3_close(database);

   }


 }
}
```

Function2 call:

```
[master insertValues:date :projectName :task :duration :comment];
```

My insert into table query, when printed in NSLog, throws up this:

INSERT INTO mastertable(_date,_projectName,_task,_duration,_comment,_status) VALUES (' Aug 26, 2010',' Staffing',' Mentoring',' 01:01',

'( > )'

,'Pending');

I think it's because of the conversion of UITextView to NSString

Please help

Sayeed

Comment: post the code of getting data from uitextview to your string...

Comment: Hey Suriya,

Please check the second block of the code, I have made a few amends.

Sayeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITextViews text property has NSString as return value, so that should not be the Problem

Comment: @ Gauloises




When I printing the insert query in log this is what I am getting:

INSERT INTO mastertable(_date,_projectName,_task,_duration,_comment,_status) VALUES ('  Aug 26, 2010','  Staffing','  Mentoring','  01:01','(
    <UILabel: 0x3947700; frame = (10 0; 280 39); text = 'Comment :             rer...'; clipsToBounds = YES; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x3947760>>
)','Pending');

Comment: as Suriya already asked, please show us some code of you getting the NSString from the textfield, the problem is most likely there

Comment: Please check the second block of the code. I have made a few amends

Comment: Hey, I think I have made some headway. When I receive the value in a textView rather than receiving it in NSString and pass textView.text as argument, it works. Can you guys figure it out now ? Please check!!

Comment: how do you "recieve" the value? Show some code of that please, as i said, there might be your problem.

Comment: I mean, instead of doing NSString *str=(UITextView *) commentText.text; which is behaving horrendously if I do (UITextView *) commentText1.text;=(UITextView *) commentText.text; and pass commentText1.text as an argument to my insert query, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the `UITextField` is properly initialized. Looks like it is pointing somewhere into memory.

Comment: I inserted the textView using the Interface builder. How do I initialize it now?

Comment: Is the connection to the IBOutlet set properly?

Comment: Hey, I am trying to insert breakpoint and check.

Sometimes it is showing "Variable is not a CFString"

Comment: Most likely that it is not connected. Check if the connection is present in Interface Builder.

Comment: I have checked in the Interface builder. It's connected. I have changed a few of its properties through code. Couldn't have done it without a connection.

Now I am trying to write the text field data in a label before I save it. The label gets the value right when I print it in the log,

NSLog(label.text);

but when I pass this label.text as argument to my insert query, it gets a null value.



Sayeed

Comment: Hey, I think I have made some headway. When I receive the value in a textView rather than receiving it in NSString and pass textView.text as argument, it works. Can you guys figure it out now ? Please check!!

Comment: Can you give some more detail on that? What do you mean by "receive"?

Comment: I mean, instead of doing 

NSString *str=(UITextView *) commentText.text;

which is behaving horrendously


if I do 

(UITextView *) commentText1.text;=(UITextView *) commentText.text;

and pass commentText1.text as an argument to my insert query, it works fine.

Comment: Sure, you are casting `commentText.text` to `UITextView` but it is of type `NSString`. That cannot work.
`NSString *str=commentText.text` is the way to do it. No need for any casts.

Answer (score 0):

@ tob,

Hey, tob I wrote the wrong code. Actually, I am not doing any casting; I am just initializing. And here is the code:

I have a UITextView commentText.text and I am extracting it's contents once the user feeds it to store it in NSString *str.
NSString *str= commentText.text;

which is behaving horrendously. When I try retrieving the value stored in str i get weird messages like "CA Layer 1048w@#" and when I insert breakpoints to check it says variable not a CFString.

However, if I create another UITextView commentText2.text just like the first one and set its size to zero as I don't want it on my screen and I do this,

commentText2.text=commentText.text;

and pass commentText2.text as the argument for my insert query, the value gets saved in the database right and is retrieved right.
Have I expressed myself?