# Setting Wallpaper (Background image) in iOS Simulator home screen or lockscreen

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator

I was scratching my brains over something when this popped in my mind. Can we set the simulator's home-screen background image to an image of our choice? Case in point is Xcode 3.2.2 simulator 3.1.3.

Comment: hey BoltClock, tried it already. Couldn't meet success. I could see the image getting saved by the name "LockBackground.jpg" in the \Applications Support\3.1.3\Library\ but it's not showing up as the background when I launch the simulator.

Have I expressed myself clearly?

Comment: Hey, I tried it on X-code 3.2.3 and simulator simulator 4.0 also. by default this simulator has "waterdrops" image as background. It's not working here as well.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Certain versions of the simulator appear to support this, not just for the home screen but for the lock screen too (which you get to with <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>):

1. Drag an image from your Mac to the simulator.
2. Mobile Safari opens. Click and hold the image.
3. Choose **Save Image**.
4. Go to Photos.app, and into the photo album.
5. Choose your image, and set it as the home screen background like you do on a device.
6. You may need to restart the simulator.

Note that since this isn't exactly officially supported, it may or may not work for you depending on your version of Xcode or the simulator.

Comment: @Bogus Boy: what happens when you try that? Which step do you have trouble at? It works perfectly for me.

Comment: Hey, Grubb told me that home-screen background is changeable only in ios4 and above. I could do it for the simulator 4.0. So, problem solved. But have a look at the textview+Nsstring thing.

Comment: Bolt if you could please look at the UITextView + NSSString issue. I have edited the original question and inserted an image as well to make communication easier.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574618/capturing-uitextview-data-in-an-nsstring

Comment: This no longer works in a simulator running iOS 5. I haven't been able to find a way to get it working; the LockBackground.jpg/HomeBackground.jpg trick does not work either.

Comment: This does not work in iOS 5 Simulator (oddly), however it does work in 6.0, 6.1, and 4.0 (as noted in **auco**'s answer).

Comment: Does not work in iOS Simulator 7.1, running iPhone 6.1 (low res). Update: it works - it just takes restarting the simulator... DOH.

Comment: @Jonny: Geez, is it really that patchy? I should probably just change my answer to say "it may or may not work".

Comment: Updated the comment... takes a restart.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible (again) with the iOS Simulator version 6 (for iOS6).

First, add some images to your photo library. You can do this by using Mobile Safari (either surf the web or drag a local image to the simulator). Then perform a long press and save to camera roll.

Second, open "Photos", select the image and set as Background.

Third, restart the simulator (this irritated me at first, as it doesn't seem to work immediately)

Answer (score 3):

How to do this for the Simulator in 11.4.

1. Drag and drop a photo on the phone.
2. Go to photo app and view app.
3. On the bottom bar you should see 3 icons.  Hit the icon with the Arrow coming out of the box like you would AirDrop it to someone.
4. On the Options panel you should see Use as Wallpaper right below the AirPlay option.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Probably, since you cannot set backgroundimage on your homescreen(exept from the locked view) on on actual iPhone pre iOS4, you cannot do so in the simulator either.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. This is the correct answer as OP's sim is at version 3.1.3.

Comment: Hey, I tried it on X-code 3.2.3 and simulator simulator 4.0 also. by default this simulator has "waterdrops" image as background. It's not working here as well.

Can anyone of you tell me why?

Comment: When you get an answer to your question that you are satisfied with you can(and should) click the check-sign to the left of the answer. This tells everyone that the question is answered and it gives the answerer credit(reputation) for answering. Read the FAQ for more information. :)

Comment: If you're running the simulator with iOS4 it should be possible. Do as BogusBoy said:
1. drag image to simulator(it opens in safari).
2. hold-click the image and select "save image".
3. got photos on home-screen.
4. select the image and set it as home-screenimage.

Comment: Yes Mr.Gubb it works just fine. Could you also tell me, what's the difference between home screen and lock screen? And this background feature is available from what simulator onwards?

Comment: And also tell me how could I retrieve the default "waterdrops" background?

Comment: voila, I just cracked this one. just delete the images from simulator\4.0..\library\springboard\ and you are good.

Comment: The homescreen is the iPhones unlocked state, where you see all your app-icons. The lockscreen is when you phone is locked.  

This feature is enabled from iOS4.  

Um, you could always reset the simulator to get the default back:

In the top-menu: Goto the "iPhone simulator"-tab and chose "Reset Content and Settings.."

Comment: I undeleted my answer for the benefit of the doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Dragged the image onto the simulator (iOS 9.3) as @boltclock suggests, but nothing happened. However, I then noticed that the images I dragged were showing up in the Photos app on the simulator. From there I just set the wallpapers the same way that you set them on a physical device. Did not need to restart the simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I thought I wasn't able to do this, but then I dragged the bottom row of options to the left and low and behold, there is the "Set as wallpaper" option.
:-)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an old question, I want to confirm this works in Simulator 13.2 for the iPhone 13 Pro Max (I'm running it on on macOS 12.2 Monterey).

1. In the simulator take Safari to the image you want to set as the background
2. Right click (or 2-finger press-click on trackpad)
3. Selected "Add to Photo"s from Pop-up menu
4. Open Photos app, and click the 'sharing' icon (box with up arrow coming out of it)
5. Scroll the popup upwards until you see the "Use As Wallpaper" menu item (if you have a Magic Trackpad, you can scroll with a three-finger swipe-up up on the  screen)

That's it. You can set the Home and Lock screen that way.

While developing an iOS iPhone app using the simulator, I copied a space scene with just stars for the background and and moved the app icons all to the home screen except left my app icon alone on a different page that way I minimized light and clutter.