# iOS Simulator black background

Tags: ios6

**iOS Simulator** black background look depressing especially with my app icon sit on its own with black background.

How can I insert background image or set my own colour of my choice?

You can do that on mac or PC with your own background. Is there a way for **iOS Simulator**?

[align top http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ios6.png](http://www.kerrydeaf.com/ios6.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go into the iOs-Simulator package, in contents/resources you will find frame.png which you can change.

Comment: Went into Xcode > Show Package Contents > Resource. But, I see nothing. I'm using Xcode 4.5?

Comment: ... Go to the actual iOS-Simulator package XD

Comment: Strange. I could not see iOS-Simulator package XD? I see it is alias but could never find the actual iOS-Simulator. I'm using iOS 6.

Comment: Solved: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625547/setting-background-image-in-simulator-home-screen