# iPhone Simulator (iPhone Retina 4 inch 64bit IOS7) change wallpaper

Tags: iphone, ios7, simulator, wallpaper

I have *xcode 5.0.2* and *iphone simulator ios7 4 inch*. How can i change its home wallpaper? I did download an image and set it as wallpaper (just like in a real iphone) but it still doesn't apply :( I also tried to rerun the simulator but nothing happens.

Can you give me ways to do it, please ?

Comment: Does this work? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13313020/ios-simulator-black-background

Comment: I have tried the same way its says. It works fine in iPhone Simulator iOS 6.0/6.1, just to restart/rerun the simulator. But unfortunately, it doesn't work using iOS7 simulator

Comment: several of the related answers seem to indicate that it may be a factor of the image in question when it failed to work.

Comment: Yeah. I also read some comments in other posts that most of the answers are like that. But which image can be used? Because the image I used works on my iPhone 4S and iPhone Simulator (iOS 6.0 and 6.1) Hmmmmm..