# Can't set IOS 7 simulator home background image

Tags: ios-simulator, xcode5

I am using IOS7 simulator. I have an image in "Photos". I set it as background image (from "Photos")  but home screen background remains black. Can you give me some advice? Thanks in advance. Is anyone alive? :)

Comment: Did any of the answers work for you?

Comment: @newenglander better late than never, so yes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drag an image from your Mac to the simulator.
Mobile Safari opens. Click and hold the image.
Choose Save Image.
Go to Photos.app, and into the photo album.
Choose your image, and set it as the home screen background like you do on a device.

This works.. Tried it on the 3.5inch iPhone retina simulator. Downloaded the stock wallpapers for iOS 7 and applied with the above steps..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it is quite easy:

> 1. Drag an image from your Mac to the simulator.
> 2. Mobile Safari opens. Click and hold the image.
> 3. Choose **Save Image**.
> 4. Go to Photos.app, and into the photo album.
> 5. Choose your image, and set it as the home screen background like you do on a device.

Source: [Setting Background image in simulator home-screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3625547/setting-background-image-in-simulator-home-screen)

Comment: I have written that i do the same, and it didnt work.

Comment: It worked fine for me. Try with another image. Maybe there's something with the one you have?

Answer (score 1):

In another plan.

1. Set wallpaper in iOS 6 environment to make LockBackground.cpbitmap
2. Place the file into following folder. (in case of 7.0.3)

   ~/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.0.3/Library/SpringBoard/LockBackground.cpbitmap
3. Restart simulator.

I hope you will get it.